# Is it possible in python to replace words in list after comparing the columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example:
I have a list and a column i.e,

```
words = ["Processing", "Rocketing", "Rocking", "Rocked", "Processed"]

  root_word  first_word second_word
0   Process  Processing   Processed
1    Rocket   Rocketing     Rockets
2      Rock     Rocking      Rocked
```

now I want to get output like

```
new_word = ["Process", "Rocket", "Rock"]
```

Basically I want to compare the words list in the last two columns, and if words found in the row of first column(i.e root_word) then that row word is appended into a new list(i.e new_word). So is it possible to do in python?

Comment: Yes, you can use for loop to loop thru each cell to check `if cell not in words` `new_word.append(cell)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_words = df[
     df['first_word'].isin(words) | df['second_word'].isin(words)
]['root_word'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the dataframe where your conditions are true using `.loc[]` and the or `|` operator

```
In[322]: df.loc[df.first_word.isin(words) | df.second_word.isin(words),'root_word'].tolist()
Out[322]: ['Process', 'Rocket', 'Rock']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.isin`:

```
words = ["Processing", "Rocketing", "Rocking", "Rocked", "Processed"]

res = df.loc[df[['first_word', 'second_word']].isin(words).any(axis=1), 'root_word'].tolist()

# ['Process', 'Rocket', 'Rock']
```